# How can I make the array dynamic?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing a site in PHP and have a graph module. I have done the graph module in that x-axis values and y-axis values are passed as array like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
    var chartData = [{
        year: 2005,
        income: 23.5
    }, {
        year: 2006,
        income: 26.2
    }, {
        year: 2007,
        income: 30.1
    }, {
        year: 2008,
        income: 29.5
    }, {
        year: 2009,
        income: 24.6
    }];
</script>
```

How can I make this array dynamic in JavaScript?

I have added the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/soumyamohanan/YDmnR/7/ but it is not working, so i have uploaded the graph to a server: http://rapidsurfing.net/mivotv/graph/bar3D.html

Any help will be appeciated.

**EDITED:**
Updated fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YDmnR/8/).

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Add to the array with `chartData.push({year: 2010, income: 99.5});`

Comment: [Your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soumyamohanan/YDmnR/7/) is sure a fun thing for us to read...

Comment: I have the array values year=(2010,2011,2012,2013) and income=(20,21,22,23,24) how can i make the above format.

Comment: @SoumyaMohanan Please read the documentation before using any tool like jsfiddle. You don't have to copy and past all the javascript from the external libraries you can add them as resources under the resources tab and you need to select the proper javascript wrapper type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, this should be what you wanted:

```
var year = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014],   //assuming you have these 2 arrays
    income = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
    chartData = [];

for(var i = 0;i<year.length;i++){
    chartData.push({
        "year": year[i],
        "income": income[i]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var chartData = new Array();
var yearlySalaryObject = {
     year : 2012,
    salary : 100000
};
chartData.push(yearlySalary);
```

This is the basic idea of what you are trying to do. Since it seems like the underlying concept isn't clear here goes: What you want to do is fill the array with a number of objects. Each object has the 'properties' year and salary. These can be added dynamically to an array using push. All arrays are dynamic in javascript. Arrays in javascript can be used as numerous different data structures. You can also just do.

```
var chartData = new Array();
chartData.push({ year : 2012, salary : 100000});
```

*NOTE: I think I severely misunderstood the question...but I am still not certain of that :) if so I don't know how to delete this answer. You should really consider rephrasing and fixing that fiddle though....

Essentially { } denotes an object and [ ] denotes array. That is why you can do what you have above. In fact, you can do as you have above and then push more of the objects into the array. Hopefully that makes sense.